# Count records with distinct days of date and match by month and year in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework, distinct

I'm new to mongodb and have a little understanding about aggregation. What I'm trying to do is to count the records in a collection with distinct days of date and with equals month and year based on user input date. There are no error but there's no display with this query.

Expected output:

```
"work_days": [
    {
        "_id": null,
        "count": 5
    }
]
```

Here's my code.

```
var staff_id = req.query.staff_id;
var date = req.query.date;
var d = new Date(date);
var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
var yy = d.getFullYear();

async.parallel({
    work_days: function(callback) {
        Timestamp.aggregate([
            {
                $project: {
                    year: { $year: "$createdAt" },
                    month: { $month: "$createdAt" }
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    staff_id: staff_id,
                    month: mm,
                    year: yy
                } 
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id : { month: { $month: "$createdAt" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt" }, year: { $year: "$createdAt" } }
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id : null,
                    count: {
                        $sum: 1
                    }
                }
            }
        ]).exec(callback);
    },
    ave_work_hours: function(callback) {
        Timestamp.count(callback);
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
    res.json(results);
});
```

And here's my database

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a94f83c234dcb690a70de72"), 
    "staff_id" : NumberInt(172), 
    "time_in" : ISODate("2018-02-25T00:45:00.000+0000"), 
    "time_out" : null, 
    "break_start" : null, 
    "break_end" : null, 
    "break_type" : null, 
    "train_delay" : false, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T06:18:36.494+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T06:18:36.494+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a94f844234dcb690a70de73"), 
    "staff_id" : NumberInt(172), 
    "time_in" : null, 
    "time_out" : null, 
    "break_start" : ISODate("2018-02-25T04:02:00.000+0000"), 
    "break_end" : null, 
    "break_type" : "60m", 
    "train_delay" : false, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T06:18:44.063+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-02-27T06:18:44.063+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

In my database i have many records with the same days and also the same month.

Comment: Just don't mind the ave_work_hours. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the expected output json ? For just a count you can replace your group with  `{ $group: { {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                    date: '$createdAt'
                }
            }, count: {$sum: 1} } }`

Comment: I updated my code.

Comment: Changed your project to include createdAt. Something like `{
                $project: {
                    year: { $year: "$createdAt" },
                    month: { $month: "$createdAt" }, createdAt:1
                }
            }`